# How to control the curvature of each edge when drawing graph object?

Tags: matlab, graph

I draw a graph following the link ( https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html  )
However, I want to edit the curvature of each edge as different values.
How can I assign the degree of curvature in each edge?
If you have any helpful site or answer, please show an example code also.
Thank you!

I can't find how to control it....

Comment: There are some different [layout options in the docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html#buofmtb-1-Layout), for anything more custom you'd likely have to write your own plotting function. It would be helpful if you [edit]ed your question to include a [mcve] with a mock-up of your desired behaviour